# Given other benefits, does the keyword 'auto' really help make debugging easier in C++?

Tags: c++, typedef, keyword, return-type, auto

Lot of people defend `'auto'` by alleging that it helps them prevent typing of very long type names faster and help you make your code more clutter free.. But I believe this comes at a significant cost during debugging. At least for me the explicit specification of the return type like `'int', 'char', 'string', etc.` is much helpful than hiding everything under the carpet with the mysterious keyword `'auto'` and later trying to figure out head and tail during debugging when your code has already grown too complex. The syntax `'typedef'` appears to be in fact more beneficial in offering the benefits of `'auto'` with some defined meanings so that it is easy to refer and quickly identify the meaning of usage in return type... How is `'auto'` more helpful than using a `'typedef'` ? What would be an effective derailment of the allegation that `'auto'` is not beneficial during debugging ?

Comment: A good read: https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: Great power comes with great responsibility. That being said please have a look at this url:- http://www.acodersjourney.com/2016/02/c-11-auto/

Comment: if your programs are small i.e for illustrative purposes of some concepts, feel free to use it. 
for complex big projects, intellisense systems might also fail to display hints, properties or methods of objects, so using `auto` is way to slow down coders a lot more. Viewing object content during debugging many times becomes infeasible. I use `auto` in limited cases particularly for long templatized container names.

Comment: Though, I already know the opinion of "Guru" Sutter and see his points, I dare to have a different opinion - may be, because I'm not a Guru at all. For the code, it's nice to have to best matching type granted by `auto`. Too sad, if I (the human before screen) have no (or even worse - a wrong) idea of that type. Hence, I don't like the `auto`. I've seen too often colleagues which admitted: Hey, I use `auto` - it will fit. When I asked Which type will it have? No idea. This is a pity if the humans don't know anymore what they are actually doing. (Does this mean, I'm a control freak?)

Comment: Regarding the keyword auto, have you seen <https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180216/does-auto-make-c-code-harder-to-understand>?

Comment: @ArchitJ Sutter again... ;-)

Comment: This is such a nice topic to discuss about. I mean this seriously. (IMHO, it's similar like endianess or whether indices for array/vector access should signed or unsigned.) Though, isn't this asking for opinions? (I hope to read some nice other comments until some killjoy will close it...)

Comment: The type inference feature that *auto* uses is applied at compile-time.  The final object file always uses the actual type of the variable and the debugger always knows how to display the object.  But if you only have a murky idea what type is used then you'll have trouble interpreting what the debugger shows you.  Then don't use auto.  A decent IDE should be able to show you what type it resolves to while you are writing the code, hover over the variable.  If you don't have such an IDE or capable text editor then you want to go shopping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving aside the fact that there are types that cannot be named (like a closure type) or can be named only with a cumbersome, repetitive, and (hence) error-prone `decltype`, the use of `auto` allows the omission of irrelevant or unhelpful information that otherwise absorbs some of the attention of the reader.

```
const auto c=mapping.key_comp();
const typename decltype(mapping)::key_compare c=mapping.key_comp();
```

What information does the second line add above that given by the first?

```
using vvi=typename std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator;
const vvi e=vec.end(),b=std::lower_bound(vec.begin(),e,x);
for(vvi i=b;i!=e;++i) // ...
```

A *typedef-name* like this has to be introduced in every function that uses it (more than once), inviting the careful reader to examine each instance to verify their equivalence, or has to be put in a larger scope (and often a different file!) that its meaningless name then pollutes.

This sort of noise doesn’t *prevent* reading the code, of course, but it slows the process down, such that any deadline *will* reduce understanding, which in turn will harm debugging.

Comment: I'd much prefer an `const auto key_compare` to a `const typename decltype(m)::key_compare c`

Comment: These are nice examples. Knowing that I cannot win this battle, I prepared a small anti-example (to illustrate my personal horror): [**Live Demo on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q0cbCCAdppLWvdRQ).